# converting mongo map reduce code to php

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have the following mongo shell code that I'm trying to use in my php application.
It's basically taking 800 evenly distributed values over a time frame, for use in a graph.

```
var map = function () {
if (endTime < 0) {
    var start = new ISODate("2013-09-01T00:00:00.000Z");
    var end = new ISODate("2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z");
    var startMilli = start.getTime(); 
    var endMilli = end.getTime(); 
    var interval = endMilli - startMilli; 
    delta = interval / 800;
    endTime = startMilli + delta;
    }
if (endTime < this.date.getTime()) { 
    resArray = {};
    while (endTime < this.date.getTime()) {
        endTime += delta; 
    }
}
    var id = this.homeId + this.sensor;
if (typeof resArray[id] == 'undefined') {
resArray[id] = 1;
emit({ 
    homeId: this.homeId, 
    sensor: this.sensor, 
    date: this.date, 
    val: this.val
}, { 
    x: 1 
});
}
};
var reduce = function (key, values) { 
return values[0];
};


db.passiv.mapReduce(
map, 
reduce, 
{ query: 
    { homeId: 35600, 
      sensor : { 
        $in :[ "z1t","ts1"] 
    }, 
    date : { 
        $gte : new ISODate("2013-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
        $lte : new ISODate("2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    } }, 
    scope : { 
        resArray : {}, 
        delta : -1, 
        endTime : -1 
    }, 
    out: 'TEST1', 
    sort : { 
        date:1 
    } 
});
```

It execute fine in the shell but my attempt to convert it to php is not giving me any results:

```
$from = '2013-09-01T00:00:00.000Z';
$to = '2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z';

$map = new MongoCode("
var map = function () {
if (endTime < 0) {
var start = new ISODate(".$from.");
var end = new ISODate(".$to.");
var startMilli = start.getTime();
var endMilli = end.getTime();
var interval = endMilli - startMilli;
delta = interval / 800;
endTime = startMilli + delta;
}
if (endTime < this.date.getTime()) {
resArray = {};
while (endTime < this.date.getTime()) {
    endTime += delta;
}
}
var id = this.homeId + this.sensor;
if (typeof resArray[id] == 'undefined') {
resArray[id] = 1;
emit({
    homeId: this.homeId,
    sensor: this.sensor,
    date: this.date,
    val: this.val},
    { x: 1 });
}
};");

$reduce = new MongoCode('
var reduce = function (key, values) {
    return values[0];
};');

$constraint = array('homeId' => 32168);
$date = array('$gte' => new MongoDate(1377986400), '$lt' => new MongoDate(1383260400));
$condition = array_merge($constraint, $date, array("sensor" => array('$in' => array('z1t', 'ts1'))));
$rs = $passivCollection->command(
array(
    "mapreduce" => "passiv",
    "query" => $condition,
    "map" => $map,
    "reduce" => $reduce,
    "scope" => array(
        "resArray" => array(),
        "delta" => -1,
        "endTime" => -1
    ),
    "out" => "TEST1",
    "sort" => array("date" => 1)
));
```

Somehow I think it's the scope in the command at the end that's not working properly and I cant seem to find anything useful on the scope aspect anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A good example of doing Map Reduce in PHP is located here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php at example #3.

Basically one of the problems you have is that the `MongoCode` objects do not represent anon functions anymore but instead a variable that cannot be returned.

Instead you want to define your functions like:

```
$reduce = new MongoCode('
function (key, values) {
    return values[0];
};
');
```

That should fix it I think.

#### edit

There is a problem with your PHP in the your edit:

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-09-01 00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-11-01 00:00:00"));
$constraint = array('homeId' => '32168');
$date = array('$gte' => $start, '$lt' => $end);
$sensors = array('z1t');
$condition = array_merge($constraint, $date, array("sensor" => array('$in' => $sensors)));
var_dump($condition);
$tt = $passivCollection->selectCollection('passiv')->count($date);
var_dump($tt);
```

You are using:

```
$date = array('$gte' => $start, '$lt' => $end);
```

Without defining a field it should search on. Try:

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-09-01 00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-11-01 00:00:00"));
$constraint = array('homeId' => '32168');
$date = array('date' => array('$gte' => $start, '$lt' => $end));
$sensors = array('z1t');
$condition = array_merge($constraint, $date, array("sensor" => array('$in' => $sensors)));
var_dump($condition);
$tt = $passivCollection->selectCollection('passiv')->count($date);
var_dump($tt);
```

Where the `date` string in:

```
$date = array('date' => array('$gte' => $start, '$lt' => $end));
```

is replaced by your field name.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your prompt answer! I changed the code and thankfully it's not giving me any errors. However the resulting collection (TEST1) is empty! ..Am I using the scope parameter correctly? Wondering what else it could be

Comment: @user1682384 nope it looks good, do you get any documents from a find function when you run the query normally?

Comment: When I do the query in the shell it seems to work fine (however slow working with 600M+ documents) but when I do the query through php nothing seems to be working. I wish I had a mongodb expert by my side.. [code](http://pastie.org/8659805)

Comment: EDIT: When I do the query in the shell it seems to work fine (however slow working with 600M+ documents) but when I do the query through php nothing seems to be working. I wish I had a mongodb expert by my side.. [code](http://pastie.org/8659831) `db.passiv.find({date:{$gte:new Date(2013,8,1),$lt:new Date(2013,10,1)},homeId:32168, sensor:'z1t'}).count()`

Comment: @user1682384 are you sure your connection is setup right? Can you show me a full isolated piece of code, from start to finish (connection setup etc) of doing this query?

Comment: Thanks again Sammaye for your time! I have posted what I have here: [link](http://pastie.org/8660030)

Comment: @user1682384 homeId is a string in PHP but not in console, that matters, make it an int in php too. What do you get now?

Comment: done. same story [link](http://pastie.org/8660113) I'm wondering if it's a server thing. the sys admin recently updated a few things on the server, mongodb was one of them, so perhaps there's an issue with the driver?

Comment: @user1682384: `DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m-Y H:i", "01/09-2013 00:00")->format('U');` returns a string. Based on your original post, I think your `date` field is a BSON date type, so you'll want to use [MongoDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) in your query (construct it accordingly). Also keep in mind that MongoDB is strict about typing. It allows comparisons of integers and floats like you might expect, but a string `"123"` will not be equal to the integer `123` or float `123.0`.